# Passing id from Create Records in Flow Builder to LWC

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-flow-builder

In flow builder is a flow screen button that leads to a Create Record element and a LWC component. It creates a record and takes the user to the client side LWC where the Id is supposed to be displayed.

Is there a way to pass newly created record id to the LWC?

Currently trying: create a flow screen after creating record, place the LWC inside, and pass the id to the LWC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this following steps :-

1. Create a variable to store record id in your lwc and make it @api
2. After creation of a record in flow store the id in a variable created in
   flow
3. Connect lwc component screen next to create record screen
4. Pass the newly created record id stored in a flow variable to variable
   created in a lwc